# Characteristic polynomial - Does it matter if the vector is column or row?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $T: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ be a linear transformation, defined by: $$T(x,y,z)= (5x-5y+5z,2x-y+z,-8x+9y-9z)$$

I have to find the characteristic polynomial of the transformation.

Does it matter if I present the transformation as a row or column vector?

What is the correct form?

$$\left( \begin {matrix} 5 & -5 & 5 \\ 2 & -1 & 1 \\ -8 & 9 & -9\end {matrix}\right)$$

Or

$$\left( \begin {matrix} 5 & 2 & -8 \\ -5 &-1 &9\\5 &1 &-9  \end {matrix}\right)$$

In order to find characteristic polynomial.

Thanks,

Alan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $$\det(A-tI)=\det((A-tI)^t)=\det(A^t-tI),$$
it doesn't matter.

Notice that the correct matrix for $T$ is the first one.